# Unique values in a grp using the DISTINCT statement?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm using SQL PLUS querying from three tables, SNUMBER, ACCOUNTS, and MYGRPS.

```
SELECT s.serialnumber,s.type,s.model,a.type,a.class, t.grp
from snumber s, accounts a, mygrps t
where s.snumber=a.snumber
and a.serialnumber=t.serialnumber
and rownum>2
```

I want to find grp's in the MYGRPS table that have duplicate values for the class column from the ACCOUNTS table.

There could be 1 to many serialnumbers in a grp, I only want to find grp's that have more than one serialnumber.

Each serialnumber has a type, model, and class. Each group should have the same class.

All serialnumbers in a grp should have the same class value from the ACCOUNTS table, so I'm looking for grp's with more than one serialnumber, that have more than one unique value in the class column, to fix those grps.

I've come up with the statement above, but need a bit of assistance. I've read a bit on the DISTINCT select statement, but I'm unsure if it could be applied here.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

You need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select t.grp, count(distinct a.class) as num_classes
from snumber s join
     accounts a
     on s.snumber = a.snumber join
     mygrps t
     on a.serialnumber = t.serialnumber
group by t.grp
having min(a.class) <> max(a.class);
```

Comment: I do need to learn more standard syntax. Thank you for the quick response. Is it just standards not to use commas in the FROM clause?